# Image classifier from text files

Tags: neural-networks, computer-vision

I have a data set of thousands of images of hundreds of pixels in gray scale ranging from -1 to 1. The labels represent 0 to 9.

The issue is that the data set is in .txt format. How can one make an image classifier using CNN without pictures but only .txt format ? I'm not sure what to do with the data set.

I need help in so far as I never did any image classifier. 
How could I break down the problem into smaller problems in order to solve this ? What are the steps involved ?

You can find the files here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/17FT76Qf40XVFWmSH5jFWjGf9KFss9xvz?usp=sharing

Comment: From a computer's POV, an image is just a huge table of color intensities for each pixel of your screen. Those text files *are* images. They're just encoded as ASCII/UTF8/whatever text data rather than some standard image format's binary data.

Comment: How can I convert them into .jpg images?

Comment: Do you *need* them to be jpgs? That sounds like an X/Y problem. If you do, you can just parse the txts to arrays of values, then use whatever library you have on hand to convert it for you to jpg. In Python, probably PIL/Pillow, but up to you.

Comment: I just convertedmy features into a numpy array. Are the images in grayscale? Do I need to convert them into RBG?